# In Chrome, how can I see what AJAX requests are being made?

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome, how can I see what AJAX requests are being made?

In Firefox I use Firebug and I can see any background AJAX request that are made.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. Open the developer tools with Ctrl-Shift-i, or via the menu at Wrench/Tools/Developer tools:
   [image: Chrome Developer Tools]
2. Click on the Network Tab:
   [image: Network Tab]
3. Click on the "XHR" link at the bottom of the list to filter the results to only AJAX requests:
   [image: XHR link]
4. Click on a request at the left to select it and use the "Headers", "Content", "Cookies" and "Timing" tabs for that request to see more details:
   [image: A good XHR request to make :)]

*You can use the [image: separate window] button in the bottom left of the tools to open the tools in their own window if you like.*

Comment: I don't have a network option, I have all the other tabs though like resources, elements, scripts, audits, ....

Comment: @Blankman Go to the wrench and choose "About Google Chrome"; that will show you your version number and also allow it to update itself to the latest version. I assume you're running an old copy.

Comment: This didnt work for me.  i have the XMLHTTPRequest logging enabled, but in the dev tools network XHR Response tab it always displays "This Request has no response data available".  It is not possible to see any ajax response in chrome (for me at least).  I have to use firebug which displays it fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what works for me on Linux and Windows 10:

- `F12` to open developer tools
- click on the network tab on the top
  list,
- select XHR (it's circled in image below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [liveHTTPHeader](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/), a chrome/firefox extension. it works pretty well.[image]

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/, https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/ are the links for firefox and chrome

Answer (score 0):

In new Chrome browsers you can press **F12** key or **CTRL+SHIFT+I** key combinations to view the Developer Tools. From there AJAX/XHR calls can be viewed through **Network** tab.