# Submitting order information

Tags: magento, checkout

Magento - Checkout Issue

In my one page checkout page, I can complete all the steps to checkout, when I click on Place Order at the final step it shows "Submitting order information" then nothing happens.

I have used firebug in Firefox to look at the issue it shows the data sending but then the process is aborted.

Comment: Did you check your server php error logs and magento {{base_dir}}/var/log)

Comment: * I checked the log and found the below error message:  
* SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction' in /home/content/00/9096700/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php  

* Also most of the magento users assuming th esolution is restarting the MySQL service. It is not possible in the shared hosting. How to overcome this issue? Kindly suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Delete cache, session and locks, then try doing transaction again, If it doesn't work use the database repair tool and repair the database.

Comment: did you tried database repair tool ?? you can download it from http://www.magentocommerce.com/download.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by looking at the XHR requests (as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939172/in-chrome-how-can-i-see-what-ajax-requests-are-being-made)).
The issue was caused by the [3D Secure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnRng.jpg) option in the payment methods for Braintree. When I disabled it, the payment went through and the order completed.