# Error hitting after sending success from PHP to Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP file receiving data from Ajax but after receiving the data I am sending a success message from php using `json_encode`, but the message `error is hit` is being alerted even though the SQL query is successful. This process worked well for localhost but when I uploaded it in main server there is an error.

Here Is my JS file:
   $(function() {
            $("#userReg_btn").click(function(e) {
                //user registration in

```
            var array = [];
            var flag = false;

            var firstName = $("#uFn").val();
            var lastName = $("#uLn").val();
            var email = $("#uEa").val();
            var pass = $("#uPn").val();
            var mobile = $("#uMn").val();
            var nID = $("#uNm").val();
            var age = $("#uAn").val();
            var prof = $("#uPc").val();


            if (firstName == "" || lastName == "" || email == "" || pass == "" || mobile == "" || nID == "" || age == "" || prof == "") {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("Please provide some input");
                flag = false;
            } else if (mobile.length != 11 || nID.length != 17) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("Please provide correct input");
                flag = false;
            } else {
                array.push(firstName);
                array.push(lastName);
                array.push(email);
                array.push(pass);
                array.push(mobile);
                array.push(nID);
                array.push(age);
                array.push(prof);

                alert(array);
                console.log(array);
                flag = true;
            }

            if (flag == true) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://demoname.co/CustomerRegistration.php",
                    data: {
                        firstName: array[0],
                        lastName: array[1],
                        email: array[2],
                        pass: array[3],
                        mobile: array[4],
                        nID: array[5],
                        age: array[6],
                        prof: array[7]
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(suc) {
                        alert("in success");
                        alert(suc);
                        console.log("success");
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        alert("error is hit");
                        alert(err);
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Form error");
            }
            alert("USer Reg");

        });
```

Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php

        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 2016 00:00:00 GMT');

        // The JSON standard MIME header.
              header('Content-type: application/json');
             $con=mysql_connect("localhost","username", "password");
             mysql_select_db("database name",$con);

                $fname = $_POST['firstName'];
                $lname=$_POST['lastName'];
                $username=$_POST['email'];
                $password=$_POST['pass'];
                $phone=$_POST['mobile'];
                $nid=$_POST['nID'];
                $age=$_POST['age'];
                $profession=$_POST['prof'];

                $query="INSERT INTO customerregistration(FirstName,LastName,Username,password,PhoneNumber,NID,Age,Profession) VALUES('$fname','$lname','$username','$password','$phone','$nid','$age','$profession');";




           if(mysql_query($query))
           {
              $suc= 'success';
              echo json_encode($suc);
           }
        else
    {
           echo  mysql_error();

    }

?>
```

Comment: What is the error? Check the ajax response.

Comment: Hit the error function in the ajax .Though It worked well in the localhost and it hits the success function but when I uploaded it in the main server it hits the error function in ajax.

Comment: OK, what conditions would cause it to hit the error function?

Comment: if the mysql query did not work properly then it will hit the error function.But query is successfully worked and data is going database .but still Error function hits. Don't know why?

Comment: Can you provide the response?

Comment: I set the alert in ajax and when it hits error function then the response "Error is a hit" popped up......If the php and Ajax code is right Then It might be servers problem....Though I am not sure.....@PHPNorton..

Comment: @AbuSufian You need to look at the actual ajax request. See this page for more info how to do it with Chrome. If you're using Firefox the process should be similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939172/in-chrome-how-can-i-see-what-ajax-requests-are-being-made

Comment: Well if you aren't sure inspect the actual request in browser dev tools. See if response body,status and headers are what are expected

Comment: @Mike I saw that and data is going PHP file ...FROM XHR the code is 200 that means data is going but No response is sent from PHP to ajax...Though I am sending using json_encode()

Comment: Just in case there is a SQL error, change to `echo  json_encode(mysql_error());` because that should still go to your `success` handler, but it needs to be proper json or else jQuery will not be able to parse it and the `error` callback will get called.

Comment: If there is no response, you might want to check your php error log.

Comment: When I send success msg to ajax and I check alert of err.statusText  and it says OK..that means response is going to ajax...Even I also check the file permission of PHP .....Still I am unable to send success to ajax....Need help

Comment: please add ; ```error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);``` at the top of your php file in order to show all erros.