# send google tag manager results to php page via ajax method GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-tag-manager

i got a few variables on my site that i push on GTM they work perfect, now i need to get variables results from gtm and send it via ajax to a php page where afterwards i'll use it to an email with the results.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready( function() {
  var msg = google_tag_manager["GTM-xxxxx"].dataLayer.get('pageName');
  var msg1 = google_tag_manager["GTM-xx"].dataLayer.get('MembershipLvl');
  var msg2 = google_tag_manager["GTM-xx"].dataLayer.get('CountryRes');
  var msg3 = google_tag_manager["GTM-xxxx"].dataLayer.get('pageLanguage');
  var getall = [msg, msg1, msg2, msg3,];
//  var me = 'just seend';    this do work
   console.log(getall);
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
    url: "url.cart.php", // some php
    data:{info: getall},
     datatype: 'html',
    success: function(data) {}
```

});
});

and here is my php

```
 <?php
```

/*
*
*/
send_mail();

function send_mail(){
    if( $_GET["info"] ) {

```
    $mail =  $_GET["info"];

    $header ="From: no-reply@test.com" . "\r\n";
    $for    = 'end@emailadaress.com';
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $title  = 'Mailing list Newsletter';
    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<br/> <p>tou got email from</p><br/>';
    $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="2">';
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($mail)."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";

    if(mail($for, $title, $message, $header)){
                    die();
    }else{
        //echo "false";
    }

}else{
    echo "false";
}
```

}

?>

the issue is that im not getting GTM variables sent, i do see them in console log, if i change variable like var = test, i do get it, but i just cant get the GTM variable sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that `$_GET["info"]` contains an array which strip_tags cannot handle. If you look at the response from your call it should have a PHP error. Somewhere along the lines of : Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. If you want to get the values out of the array you can either build a loop or reference the particular index. 
LOOP

```
foreach ($mail as $gtm) {
    $message .= $gtm;
}
```

INDEX

```
$message .= $mail[0] // google_tag_manager["GTM-xxxxx"].dataLayer.get('pageName');
$message .= $mail[1] // google_tag_manager["GTM-xx"].dataLayer.get('MembershipLvl');
```

etc...

[PHP strip tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)  
 [Foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)  
 [How to view a ajax call in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939172/in-chrome-how-can-i-see-what-ajax-requests-are-being-made)

Comment: i'm actually adding the changes you told me, but i also tried to send just 1 varbaile out of array example   "var msg" and still i got nothing

Comment: I would have to see the header request, have a look at the link I attached to my answer on how to view a ajax request in chrome.

Comment: thank you so much, after fixing issues with ajax, i needed the loop, now it's working