# i am trying to give an "hello world" in client side browser with express and http.?

Tags: node.js, express

here is my code app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.use(express.static('Public'));

app.get("/send", function (request, response) {
 response.sendFile('index.html', {root : './views'});
});

var listener = http.listen(process.env.HOSTNAME || 
'myhostname.com/nodejs/restapi' ,function(){
 console.log('server running');
  });
```

and my views/index.html

```
<script src="../client.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

and my Public/client.js

```
 $(function() {
    $.get('/Nodejs/Restapi/send', function(send) {
      console.log('hello world :o');
   });
});
```

i dont know whats wrong its working perfectly in localhost

Comment: What exactly is not working? Your question does not make it clear what you expect to happen, what actually happens, and what error messages you are getting.

Comment: I'm trying  to upload to server through FTP and want to execute my node app.js.

Comment: Error throws as Forbidden to my client.js file, and Url i cant reach to myhostname.com/Nodejs/Restapi which i need to call as API to my further project implementation.

Comment: The ajax call from the browser isn't working? Can you post the full response from the develop menu's network tab?

Comment: @zekeS. i dont get!!  whats network tab??

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939172/in-chrome-how-can-i-see-what-ajax-requests-are-being-made

Comment: yeah it works in localhost..but i have to write it to my server through FTP and run from client side browser (client.js).but it should work in "www.hostname.com/nodejs/restapi",(path in which im uploading my node application to server).